# Why was my UK visa processing delayed?

Tags: visas, uk, delays

I got the following email on 4th day of priority visa service. My application is for tier4 visa.

> Thank you for your UK visa application which has been received and is
> under consideration.  We aim to process applications:
>
> Non-settlement within 15 working days Priority Visas within 5 working
> days Settlement within 60 working days.
>
> Unfortunately, we will not be able to make a decision on your visa
> application within these service standards because we require further
> information to fully assess your application. We will contact you
> should we require any additional information from you.
>
> Please be assured that we will continue to progress your application
> to enable a decision to be made as soon as possible. We will notify
> you by email once a decision has been made.

If anyone else has received the same email? Or does this mean there will be an interview when they send this email?

Comment: Pretty sure there’ve been similar questions on TSE before. The email means exactly what it says - UKVI is still assessing your application. AFAIK there is no interview process, you’ll just get an email with the decision once it’s been made. How long that will take is unknowable.

Comment: They say they need time to get additional information, but likely won’t need information from you.